# Read a .txt file of SD in Android

Tags: java, android, file, sd-card

My problem with the software I'm trying to make is this;
when I save the information, it's saved with this code:

[image: Code i save]

With this, the information is saved in a text in the SD,
but I couldn't to read that information. I've tried with several ways.

I want to save the content of the TXT in a String to put it in a TextView.

Comment: Please include code as text (with code formatting) and not as picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        I have tried this code and it works perfectly :D
```

> File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
>             File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), "datos.txt");
>
> ```
>       BufferedReader fin =new BufferedReader(
>               new InputStreamReader(
>                       new FileInputStream(f)));
>       String texto = fin.readLine();
>       fin.close();
>
>       textohere.setText(texto);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
            {
                String myData ;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(your file name);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 myData = myData + strLine;
            }
                in.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
               // play with myData..It's file content
```